# Nested Routes Show Action: What objects does it expect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the relevant line from my rake routes:

```
 client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#show
```

When I try passing in the objects like `<%= client_note_path([client, @notes.first]) %>>` I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"notes", 
:client_id=>[#<Client id: 5, ... , #<Note id: 9, ...]}
```

Which made me think to try a client ID. So, I tried: `<%= client_note_path([client.id, @notes.first]) %>`

which gives me:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"notes", :client_id=>[5, 
#<Note id: 9,content: "He just bought a brand new bobcat, be sure to charg...", 
client_id: 5, created_at: "2012-06-11 16:18:16", 
updated_at: "2012-06-11 16:18:16">]}
```

Which, made me want to try just passing in a client ID. `<%= client_note_path(client.id) %>`

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"notes", :client_id=>5}
```

Still not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to show an individual note which can normally be found at a url like looks like: `http://localhost:3000/clients/2/notes/3/`

What object(s) does it expect?

*Complete Routes File and Rake Routes*

```
           users GET    /users(.:format)                             users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                             users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                         users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                         users#destroy
        sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                          sessions#create
     new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                      sessions#new
         session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                      sessions#destroy
    client_notes GET    /clients/:client_id/notes(.:format)          notes#index
                 POST   /clients/:client_id/notes(.:format)          notes#create
 new_client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/new(.:format)      notes#new
edit_client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id/edit(.:format) notes#edit
     client_note GET    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#show
                 PUT    /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
                 DELETE /clients/:client_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#destroy
         clients GET    /clients(.:format)                           clients#index
                 POST   /clients(.:format)                           clients#create
      new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                       clients#new
     edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                  clients#edit
          client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                       clients#show
                 PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                       clients#update
                 DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                       clients#destroy
            root        /                                            clients#index
          signup        /signup(.:format)                            users#new
          signin        /signin(.:format)                            sessions#new
         signout DELETE /signout(.:format)                           sessions#destroy
```

And:

```
resources :users 
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :clients do
  resources :notes
end

root to: 'clients#index'

match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

*Additional Info:*

Changing the line to `<%= client_note_path(client, @notes.first) %>` results in:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"notes", :client_id=>#<Client id: 6, 
company_name: "John and Sons Roofing", contact_name: "John Wonder", phone_number: "1-    
555-283-9999", email_address: "bob@example.com", street_address: "13 Oak Street", city:
"Oakville", state: "Iowa", zip: "53457", image_location: "http://image-
location.com/image/john.jpg", created_at: "2012-06-11 16:18:16", updated_at: "2012-06-11    
16:18:16", url: "www.johnroofing.com">, :id=>nil}
```

Which gives me an id of nil. But, I have `<%= @notes.first.blank? ? "No Notes" : @notes.first.content%>` and that returns the notes content, so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Also, let's try it with id, just for fun! `<%= client_note_path(client.id, @notes.first.id) %>`

And now we get: `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`. Looking into the DB, the ID of the note is 9 and 5 for the client.

Comment: what does your route file look like?

Comment: @IAmNaN updated. Will finish formatting.

Comment: That's the output from `rake routes`. I guess I can reverse it but what I was asking for was your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: Sorry, IAmNaN. I should have paid more attention. I'll update it after trying the suggestions below.

Comment: NoahClark, this is a different question now, but you should examine your `client` object. Is it nil? Where is it set? Should you be using `@client` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you are putting the objects into an array as a single parameter rather than just passing two parameters.  The proper way is

```
client_note_path(client, @notes.first)
```

Note that you can pass in the object itself (as shown), or the id of the object for either or both.

Comment: See update above. This was at least a partial solution to the problem.

Comment: How do you get @notes?  Can you post line in the controller that assigns that variable?  That seems to be where the issue is.  You can always test that your route works by temporarily using  `client_note_path(client, Note.find(9))` in your view for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: I can confirm that that the Note.find(9) works. However, I'm actually setting @notes in the view like like this                    `<% @notes = client.notes.all %>`. I know this is a Bad Thing, but I am looping over each client via `<% @clients.each do |client| %>` and so want to use the client in each block. Which, as far as I know I can't do in the controller.

Comment: not sure what I changed, but couldn't sleep tonight so decided to try to work on this some more and got it working via `<%= link_to @notes.first.content, client_note_path(client.id, @notes.first.id) %>`

Comment: Are you saying that you set @notes multiple times in the same view for different clients?  In that case a plain local variable would make more sense than an instance variable, or you could just continue to use `client.notes` on it's own, without assigning it to a variable. For example, you could use `client_note_path(client.id, client.notes.first.id)`.  I'm glad you got it working, now it's time for refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

The `client_note_path` method expects *two, count 'em, two* arguments:

```
client_note_path(client, note)
```

A `Client` object and a `Note` object. Or an id that represents a `Client` and another for a `Note` object.

The problem you're having is because you didn't tell it what note you wanted, or you used an array. By using an array, it would make it only receive one argument.